# Load google chart image url in iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show concentric pie chart from google chart api but the imageData variable returns null value and image doesn't loaded.

Please check following code for reference:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=pc&chd=t:120,45|120,60,50,70,60&chs=300x200&chl=||helo|wrd|india|pak|ban&chco=FFFFFF|FFFFFF,e72a28|a9d331|ffce08|8a2585|184a7d"]];
UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
self.myImageView.image=myimage;
```

Help me to solved this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

used url string encoding method to recover from this problem,

like this-

```
NSString *str=@"your respected url";
NSString *myurl=[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```